# Transfer files over telnet?

Tags: serial-port, telnet

I need to transfer some ASCII files from one machine to another over telnet. How to send files over telnet?

I know that in minicom etc... you can use zmodem (control a - s), is there a similar thing?

Comment: Transfer over ethernet, wifi, ...  My guess is that you are looking for FTP.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422148/is-there-a-way-to-copy-a-file-over-telnet

Comment: its connecting over USB networking to an embedded system. Usually use minicom over RS232 but the port has died, hence need to do the same over telnet or some such protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a telnet client that can transfer files using zmodem. Not all of them can and certainly the standard telnet client that comes with Windows or Linux doesn't. Off the top of my head I think ZOC (proprietary) supported zmodem.

If you don't HAVE TO use telnet, ssh/scp is a much better option.

Comment: Im on Debian Linux. I cant use SSH really as its connecting over USB networking to an embedded system and so i dont need the security, and cant afford the CPU overhead the encryption will cause.

Comment: If you have a TCP link then you can probably use FTP or (TFTP the latter is much more lightweight)

Comment: Thanks, ill try (t?)FTP. or maybe just wget stuff off an apache server running on the development PC.